# Push Notification In Ionic-Framework Using Reactjs

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, push-notification, capacitor

```
const register = () => {
    PushNotifications.register();

    PushNotifications.addListener("registration", (token: Token) => {
        console.log(token, "Push Notification token");
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener("registrationError", (error: any) => {
        console.log(
            JSON.stringify(error),
            "Push Notification error on registration"
        );
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener(
        "pushNotificationReceived",
        (notification: PushNotificationSchema) => {
        console.log("Push notification received: ", notification);
        setNotifications((notifications) => [
            ...notifications,
            {
                id: notification.id,
                title: notification.title,
                body: notification.body,
                type: "foreground",
            },
        ]);
        }
    );

    PushNotifications.addListener(
        "pushNotificationActionPerformed",
        (notification: ActionPerformed) => {
        console.log(
            notification.notification.data,
            "Push notification action performed"
        );
        setNotifications((notifications) => [
            ...notifications,
            {
                id: notification.notification.data.id,
                title: notification.notification.data.title,
                body: notification.notification.data.body,
                type: "action",
            },
        ]);
        }
    );
};
```

This is my register function for push notification I am trying to log Notification data sent from firebase but not receiving that inside @pushNotificationActionPerformed listener notification.notification.data.

I have tried to log @notification.actionId and @notification.notification but in the result I am not receiving body and title which I am receiving in @pushNotificationReceived listener when app is opened.

Can anyone help me with that?